# How strong is Magellan?

Tags: one-piece

He was trusted to guard the World Government's maximum-security prison from the most dangerous criminals and pirates from all over the world, he must be extremely strong. The main reason for the mass breakout success was because he was tricked but not defeated.
Is he at par with the Admiral? Or maybe somewhere lower than that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go by status alone to indicate someone's actual power.

> After the great breakout out of Impel Down, he was demoted to Vice-Warden. Probably because of his pride. So based on status alone you would think Hannyabal to be stronger than Magellan, which we know he is not.
>  
>  [image: Vice-Warden !]
>  
>  Well he wasn't before the timeskip. We haven't seen either of them after that, so it's hard to say where they stand now.

In the One Piece power system, it is actually hard to say who is stronger in general, since it depends on lots of factors, like who you are up against. For example, Crocodile was much stronger than Luffy, but Luffy still beat him by using the water trick. In my opinion I think he wouldn't be far off the admiral's level, since he beat Blackbeard's crew with just one hydro attack. Actually Magellan's power and ability makes him the perfect guy for the job and wouldn't be a good admiral. He would have a hard time arresting someone without mortally poisoning him.

Comment: Spoiler formatting is a little bit weird; I've edited your post to move the image into a spoiler block.

Comment: To add to this in more government context. Garp is generally hailed as someone incredibly powerful and already noted as someone who should have been admiral and even fleet admiral but was content at Vice Admiral.  Same thing for a lot of positions revealed over time, they dont always equal the strength of the character.  Sometimes they are weaker like Captain Fullbody or Morgan.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know as One Piece is relative, however there are a few facts that help determine this better.  Also here's a related post: [Haki vs.Venom Venom Fruit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13315/haki-vs-venom-venom-fruit/13350#13350)

No real way to train against being poisoned at Magellan's level of poisons, while some people like Mr. 3 and Ivankov seem to have counter measures. Even Gold Roger died from disease which indicates Haki/fortitude doesn't help against physiological changes.

He jailed and kept in line the world's worst criminals:

- Many of Blackbeard's crew including Shiryu, Logia users, and strong Haki users.
- Blackbeard (Yonkou) and crew were completely defeated by him. It is also worth noting that Shank's scar was given by Blackbeard before he even got the Yami Yami fruit. 1 Yonkou = Marines + Piratelords per Government's assessment.
- Positions are also based on intelligence, career drive and politics.
- He spent most of the day in the bathroom as he ends up poisoning his own food which his stomach can't handle. This can be argued as a negative for a position like admiral which is publicly visible.
- It was never established whether or not he can use Haki. A lot of fruit users, especially powerful ones, tend to rely more on their fruits like Ace and Kizaru.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that his devil fruit is of Paramecia type, he cannot be on par with admirals. Also it is unknown whether he can change his poison's composition like Coco from Toriko. If he can change then he can be considered somewhat dangerous. If he cannot change then he seems pretty useless as Iva-san had antidote for his poison. He could guard the prison because the prison had many other supporting features to trap the convicts. But that also failed. So he cannot be on same league as Admirals but much lower than them.

Comment: it is incorrect to say that a character is powerful or not just on the basis of his/her devil fruit , even paramecia types who know haki are at times at par with those of the logia type . Whitebeard had gura gura no mi ( which is paramecia ) but he was powerful than the admirals !

Comment: absolutely correct. can't say anything about that. but magellan didn't show any inclination of having haki. And although it can't be compared on basis of type of fruit, but being intangible is an added advantage which is not there with paramecia.

Comment: I would say he is more powerful than Croc (who is a logia) or Gecko and likely some haki users.  I highly doubt he is as strong as an admiral (they are the strongest in the marines besides (sometimes) their bosses and Magellan is in the marines) but you can't just look at the devil fruit. It is strongly implied that Shanks is stronger than an admiral and he doesn't seem to have any devil fruit. Raliegh definitely doesn't and held his own against an admiral. Again, they have haki but Luffy defeated 2 cannon logias without haki.

Comment: He cannot be equal as an admiral, knowing that admirals can use Haki while Magellan cannot. He is definitely strong, the fact that he is guarding Impel Down. In comparison, I could he is as strong as a warlord neglecting Haki.

Comment: @maseru There is no evidence he doesn't know Haki.  Some fruit users simply just rely on their fruits more, like Kizaru or Ace.  Also his power makes him one of the most dangerous people in the world as even Blackbeard (Yonkou) got his butt handed to him by Magellan.

Comment: @Sp0T logia isn't necessarily the most powerful though for it automatically puts you on a higher playing field.  Also Sengoku (Fleet Admiral) was a Zoan type.

Comment: @Sp0T To answer wether he can change the poison type, he can.  It was actually stated he has different versions of poisons.  His final version of the poison is an instant kill and can infect/destroy everything it touches including the ground (akin to acid). Also Ivankov didn't have an antidote, he just made Luffy's body go into overdrive to neutralize it. However Shiryu does have an antidote to atleast some of his poisons, as he saves blackbeard with it. http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Magellan

Answer (score -1):

> Is he at par with the Admiral? Or maybe somewhere lower than that?

Possibly around the levels of Vice admirals but then again some of the Vice admirals are extremely strong like [Issho](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Issho); now an Admiral.

Again like @PeterRaeves mentioned, position alone doesn't determine the strength. Its relative.

Comment: First part is a baseless comment. Please provide support if there is any for this.  As your second part mentioned it is all relative in the one piece world.