# Haki vs.Venom Venom Fruit

Tags: one-piece

### Knowledge:

---

**Busoushoku Haki:**

This Haki can be used as armor against strong attacks or devil powers.

> This type of Haki also has the ability to bypass the powers of a Devil
>   Fruit user, touching the "substantial body" beneath whatever
>   protection the fruit provides, such as the case of body-altering Devil
>   Fruits such as Logia or Paramecia users.

[image]

---

**Venom Venom Fruit:**

> The Doku Doku no Mi is a Paramecia-type Devil Fruit that grants the
>   user the ability to produce and control different types of poison
>   [...]
>   any person who touches the user will be poisoned.

So everything Magellan touches gets poisoned...

[image]

---

***So if Luffy could have used haki, would that have prevent him from getting poisoned?***

Comment: This question makes me think what happen if Haki user coated himself with haki and get attack by devil fruit power like this poison or magma or anything.... Busoushoku Haki more like offensive type rather than defensive

Comment: He can touch or attack him without getting poisoned, but I don't know if it makes him immune to Magelan poison attack.

Comment: A good place to look seems to be Luffy's use of haki+gear3 on poisonous/concrete making giant gas guy Ceaser.  Were his hands immune due to the haki, the poison immunity, or the oversized hands reverting back to normal? (unfortunately I think it is the last one)

Comment: @kaine I don't think the fight between Caesar and Luffy is a good example since the poisonous gas was not part of Caesar, he just manipulated the gas, but technically speaking it wasn't part of his body.

Comment: @peterraeves I agree largely in that it was a different situation but as magellan's power is not a logia, the poison isnt part of his body either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Haki wouldn't help him.  It was established that many prisoners knew how to use Haki and that Magellan was the only one capable of keeping them in line.  Furthermore Blackbeard and his crew are potent haki users, he definitely got his butt handed to him only to be saved with the antidote from Shiryu.

Its good to note that while haki lets you hit the body of users, it doesn't negate powers like the sea, or yami yami fruit.  While the Haki user can hit Magellan which was never an issue for Luffy, it poisons anyone who has contact with it.

Similar issues are present with some other paramacia users like Sugar in the Donquixote Pirates where contact with her turns even haki users to toys.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this debate, consider the following scenarios:

- Ace's Death
- Pica's defeat

**Case 1**
In the case of Ace as a logia user, why wasn't the admiral burned from punching fire? His power was greater than Ace's power was.

**Case 2**
How did Zoro actually cut pica with a haki coated sword when pica had both haki armor and devil fruit? 
His haki was stronger

In both cases the haki user on the attacking end just so happened to be stronger. In the end I think it comes down to who has more mastery of either the haki or the devil fruit and in Magellan's case with the prison he just so happened to be stronger.

Now this is pretty opinion based but I believe that if Luffy hit Magellan the way he is now Gear 4+ King Kong Gun. Magellan would not be strong enough to protect himself and overpower the negation of Luffy's haki

Comment: Where are you getting the information for case 1? Based on my recollections, Akainu's ability to injure Ace did not come from haki. He stated, "Did you think you would be okay because you're made of fire?" which implied that it was merely his logia type powers overpowering Ace's. Presumably it was also his logia powers that kept him from being burned by Ace's fire. The wiki corroborates my memory: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sakazuki :"Akainu said that his magma can smother Ace's fire and was thus able to injure Ace despite his Logia intangibility"

Comment: You are correct. My memory of that fight is a bit hazy. That fight was pre-time skip and before haki became a real concrete thing. My answer is now editted.

Answer (score -1):

I think that he would've still been poisoned since Haki is an offensive technique and not a defensive one, plus Luffy would still have to hit the main body: like when Luffy couldn't hit Trebol on Dressrosa because he moved his body around inside his snot body